# My app crashes when i attempt to close the keyboard by clicking the scroll view

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, scrollview

I have been attempting to make it so you can click the screen to hide the keyboard. The code i am using here makes the app crash. I found a method to close the keyboard when the screen is used to scroll but not on a touch. Error is as follows and the bit contained with * * is the part that breaks the app upon touching the scroll view with the keyboard up.
       LoginViewController dismissKeyboard]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fdba2786540
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-LoginViewController dismissKeyboard]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fdba2786540'
*** First throw call stack:
        class LoginViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

```
@IBOutlet weak var userEmailLogin: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var userPasswordLogin: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var scroller: UIScrollView!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    scroller.contentSize.height = 500
    self.userEmailLogin.delegate = self
    self.userPasswordLogin.delegate = self



 *var tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "dismissKeyboard")

    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

    func dismissKeyboard() {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }*



    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)

}
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}
@IBAction func loginButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {



}
```

Comment: In your UITapGestureRecognizer you are setting an action called dismissKeyboard, try removing it, or create a function (outside the viewDidLoad) that is called dismissKeyboard. The error basicly means that something is calling a method or property on your view controller that does not exist.

Comment: @SanderSaelmans is right :) I think that dismissKeyboard() is local to viewDidLoad() (like any other local variable) and it's destroyed when it's done. Moving it outside should do the trick :)

Comment: thank you! problem solved.  my first post and i'm probably spoiled by the response time, but regardless, this is amazing.